# Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app). - In React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

When i look up this error its with flutter or React Native. All the the solutions I have come  across did not help.

I have also done it like this . If i do i get a - Maximum call stack size exceeded error

```
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

```
import {firebase} from './firebase'
import {getFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore'
import {getStorage} from 'firebase/storage'


const firebaseConfig ={
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};


const db = getFirestore()
const storage = getStorage()
const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp()




export {db,storage,firebase,app}
```

Comment: Can you share this file? `import {firebase} from './firebase'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what is being imported as `firebase` at the top, but you must initialize Firebase before any other service but currently it's the opposite way. Try refactoring the order of statements as shown below:

```
// import { firebase } from './firebase'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage'


const firebaseConfig = {...};

// Initialize Firebase first
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const db = getFirestore()
const storage = getStorage()

export {db, storage, firebase, app}
```

Also if that `./firebase` file just has this statement `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` which is older syntax then can you try removing the file?